# Does signed APK file contains mac address of the computer where the APK is signed?

Tags: android, apk

Does a signed APK file contains mac address of the computer where the APK is signed?

If I have a malicious APK file, can I track down where it comes from?

Comment: decompile the APK and check it.

Comment: @Pinch: you do realize that MAC addresses are not set in stone and can be changed at will? Not to mention that a significant number of modern computers have multiple MAC addresses.

Comment: Also there is no centralized db of MAC addresses, and that MAC addresses aren't sent past the first router so trying to track them over the internet would be impossible.  In other words, no and MACs don't work like that.

Comment: I gotta ask: what makes you ask if the MAC address would be provided inside an APK? As others points out, a MAC address can be cloned and changed to whatever you like. Also a MAC address is usually not publicly known...